# How to autopublish a dialog flow bot in slack

Tags: slack, dialogflow-cx

I have a bot in dialogflow with slack integration, and need it to be auto publish, like that:

The user send a specific command like:

`update bot`

and dialog flow publish a new version.

Can this be possible? How can I do this?

Comment: Which Dialogflow [Edition](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/editions) are you currently using: Dialogflow ES or CX?
  
  
Also, by “publish”, do you mean you need the Dialogflow Agent’s latest draft to be turned into a version and published to an environment (as in this documentation for [ES](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/agents-versions) or [CX](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/version)), or to instead having the Agent re-trained? 
   
  
Can you overall please clarify your use case?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to clarify what you mean with *"auto publish"*. Dialogflow is a tool for building conversational flows, and you can link the identification "project/location/agent" to your custom integration or a pre-defined one.

This means that whenever you **apply modifications** to your conversation flow in the Dialogflow console and **save** them, they should be automatically **available** in your bot (from Messenger or from your website or from a Slack Bot or wherever).
No need to "publish" a new version unless you're using their versioning system. In that case, you could just **use the same "environment"** and link it to an integration and then *update the flow versions* inside that environment.

Instead, if you're referring to "updating" data of your bot (for example your weather bot has an "update" intent which fetches the new weather conditions) that can be managed via webhook: you should define the "update intent" first and then create a route or route group that brings you to a page with a web hook enabled, calling an API service for the weather like Open Weather Map.